# What is the difference between Core and Task node in EMR

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am using Amazon EMR , what is the difference between the core node and task nodes In EMR?

If I have 20 GB of Data should I give more computation to my Core nodes or task nodes?

Please can someone explain how 20 gb of data will be processed with such Configurations given below.

**core node Config**

```
c3.8xlarge
32 vCore, 60 GiB memory, 640 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as32units

m5.xlarge
4 vCore, 16 GiB memory, EBS only storage
EBS Storage:64 GiB
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as4units
i3.xlarge

4 vCore, 30.5 GiB memory, 950 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as4units
```

**Task Node Config**

```
c3.8xlarge
32 vCore, 60 GiB memory, 640 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as32units

c3.4xlarge
16 vCore, 30 GiB memory, 320 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as16units

c3.xlarge
4 vCore, 7.5 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as4units

m5.xlarge
4 vCore, 16 GiB memory, EBS only storage
EBS Storage:64 GiB
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as4units
```